# Filter for field of current node

Tags: views, 8

I want to list (in a views block) only teasers of articles that are younger than the current node.

Somehow I have to use the current node from url->field_date for filtering. Is this possible with views via the UI (Contextual Settings)?

Or do I have to create a module for that? If so... which hook should I use.. how to tell the view to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think its possible with just configuration and/or contrib modules.

I believe you have to override `hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)` and add  `$query->addWhereExpression` based on the current nodes date field.

Dig in `core/modules/datetime/src/Plugin/views/filter/Date.php function opSimple($field)`  and perhaps [core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/filter/Date.php function opSimple($field)](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.6.x/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/filter/Date.php#L180) to see how they properly use the `addWhereExpression`

Comment: Thanks GiorgosK. I just used the hook_views_query_alter hook. Actually the only thing I have to do is to change one value in the query:

The static value I added in views I have to override:

2017-08-27T14:56:26 should become node.field_date.value.


How to achieve this?

Comment: see my revised answer otherwise you will need to do a QUICK and dirty `str_replace` on the `$query->where` array (appropriate condition)

Comment: $date = new DateTime($release_date, new DateTimeZone(Drupal::config('system.date')->get('timezone')['default']));
                    $value = sprintf('%d', $date->getTimestamp() + $date->getOffset());
                    $query->addWhereExpression(0, "node__field_release_date.field_release_date_value > $value");

Comment: I don't seem to use the addWhereExpression function correctly